# Bootstrap: Checkbox and Textbox not matching up in size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a checkbox associated with a text box (the checkbox will enable/disable the textbox). I've used bootstrap to style the two of them, however the textbox is not as vertically large as the checkbox's surrounding grey box (as can be seen in the attached screenshot)

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            @Html.LabelForConfig(model => model.PushRetroActivityDays)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsRetroActivityDaysForPush)
                                </span>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PushRetroActivityDays)

                            </div><!-- /input-group -->
                        </div><!-- /.col-md-9 -->
                    </div>
```

How can I make the two match up (ideally I'd like to make the text box vertically larger rather than shrinking the grey box surrounding the checkbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this way...**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/sywneaup/1/)**

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
          <div class="input-group">
           <span class="input-group-addon">
           <input type="checkbox" aria-label="..."/>
           </span>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..."/>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
```

Comment: this works for your example but not for mine. I tried applying the class to the Dropdown using: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PushRetroActivityDays, new { @class = "form-control" }) but it doesn't appear to be sticking